# Javascript for dynamic url content

Tags: javascript, html

I have a html link reference something like:

```
click here<a href="http://www.example.com/usr/page.aspx?pgid=1">www.example.com</a>
```

Now I want to add javascript tags to make the www.example.com url to be dynamic. so it will always retrieve as

```
<a href="[DYNAMIC URL]/usr/page.aspx?pgid=1">www.example.com</a>
```

Can anyone please advice?TQ

Comment: Don't you have backend? What is the dynamic means in your terms?

Comment: Is that what you want `<a href="/usr/page.aspx?pgid=1">www.example.com</a>` ? Will be interpreted by browser with current hostname, protocol, port.

Comment: @dfsq yes, and i want the script to get any domain from the URL which the user visit. Means if the user visit site1.com. it will go to "site1.com/usr/page.aspx?pgid=1"

Comment: So try what I suggested, looks like this is your solution.

Comment: If you change your link to `<a href="/usr/page.aspx?pgid=1">www.example.com</a>`, when a user visits a page served by site1.com, the link will point to `http|https://site1.com//usr/page.aspx?pgid=1`

Comment: You can make a JS dynamic url loader, and call it by `<a onClick="method()"></a>` maybe.

Comment: @Ren ... Check my answer and see if that's what you're looking to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for? [Check JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/1vua2ug5/)

HTML

```
<a class="dyna" href="[DYN]/usr/page.aspx?pgid=1">www.example.com</a><br/>
<a class="dyna" href="[DYN]/usr/page.aspx?pgid=1">www.site.com</a><br/>
<a class="dyna" href="[DYN]/usr/page.aspx?pgid=1">www.bla.com</a><br/>
```

JS

```
var l = document.getElementsByClassName("dyna").length;

for (var i=0; l > 0; l--){
    var inner = document.getElementsByClassName("dyna")[i].innerHTML,
        x = document.getElementsByClassName("dyna")[i].getAttribute('href'),
        y = x.replace('[DYN]','http://'+inner);

    document.getElementsByClassName("dyna")[i].setAttribute('href',y);

    i++
}
```

Note: I used a class to retrieve the anchors but you can look for TagName a if you prefer ...

Answer (score 0):

Using javascript get domainname and add it to create link you need.

```
var domain = document.domain;
var link = '<a href=\"'+domain+'/usr/page.aspx?pgid=1\">www.example.com</a>';
link // here you get a anchor tag html.
```

To get the domain name example.com from the set of possible subdomains sub1.example.com sub2.example.com sub3.example.com. you can try below code.

```
var parts = location.hostname.split('.');
var subDomain = parts.shift();
var upperLevelDomain = parts.join('.');

To get only the second-level-domain, you might use

var secondLevelDomain = parts.slice(-2).join('.');
```

Answer (score 0):

The `href` attribute can be a relative<sup>1</sup> path:

```
<a href="/path/to/page">Blah</a>
```

The link would grab the current protocol, host, and port and append whatever comes next.

Sample scenario: let's pretend the current URL is `http://yoursite.com/pages/links.html` the above example anchor would navigate when clicked to `http://yoursite.com/path/to/page`.

NOTE: If you omit the leading slash in the relative path

```
<a href="path/to/page">Blah</a>
```

The current *full path* will be used.

Sample scenario: let's pretende the current URL is `http://yoursite.com/pages/links.html` then the anchor without leading slash would navigate when clicked to `http://yoursite.com/pages/path/to/page`

<sup>1</sup>: *relative* as in *relative to the current page*